# Why do calculated fields not show up in form to send email?

Tags: javascript, php, email

This is a very small version of a larger project just to illustrate the point. The disabled calculated field value 'appletot' does not show up in the email from form to send. Any ideas why and how it might be made to do so?

```
<body>
<form name="fruit" id= "fruit" action="acknowlfruit.php" method="post"  
target="_self">
<fieldset>
<table onkeyup="computeAll()">
<tr><th>Fruit</th><th>No.</th><th>Price</th><th>Total</th></tr>
<tr><td> <label for ="apples" class="label">Apples:</label></td>
<td> <input id= "apples" name="apples" type="text" required class="input" 
value="0" size="3" maxlength="3" indent= "250px" /> </td>
<td>at 5p</td>
<td><input id="appletot" type = "text" class= "input" value="0" size="5" 
maxlength="10" disabled/></td></tr>
</table>  
<br/> 
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
function computeAll() {
document.fruit.appletot.value = 5*document.fruit.apples.value;
}
</script>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Fruit Cost';
$message .= 'Apples: '.$_POST['apples']."  ";
$message .= 'Cost of apples: '.$_POST['applestot']."\r\n\r\n";
$success = mail($to, $subject,$message, $headers);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`disabled` fields are not passed to server. Use `type="hidden"` or even count total on server side instead:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $to = 'myemail@gmail.com'; 
   $subject = 'Fruit Cost';
   $message .= 'Apples: '.$_POST['apples']."  ";
   $message .= 'Cost of apples: '.($_POST['apples'] * 5)."\r\n\r\n";
   $success = mail($to, $subject,$message, $headers);
}
```

Second approach is **safer** because user **can change** client javascript, for example with:

```
function computeAll() {
    document.fruit.appletot.value = 0.5 * document.fruit.apples.value;
}
```

How will you find **where is the error** in this case?